# Terminating recursive query with a condition on entire level of recursion - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

Say i have the following table, called *graph*:

| `_id` | `relates` |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `{2, 3}` |
| `2` | `{4}` |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` |
| `4` | `{3, 7}` |
| `5` | `{}` |
| `6` | `{}` |
| `7` | `{}` |

Here it is in graph form:
[*graph*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuOu8.png)

My problem is to write a recursive query to find the shortest path between two nodes. In this example i will aim to find the shortest path between nodes 1 and 3.

The following query works fine and solves the problem.

```
    with recursive pathFrom1to3(_id, relates, lvl, _path) as
        (
            select _id, relates, 1 as lvl, ARRAY[_id]
            from graph
            where _id = 1
        union
            select g._id, g.relates, p.lvl+1 as lvl, _path || g._id
            from pathFrom1to3 p join graph g on g._id = any(p.relates)
            where not g._id = any(p._path) -- handles cycles (not applicable for this example)
        )
    
    select * from pathFrom1To3
    where _id = 3
    limit 1
```

The recursive query actually finds **all** possible paths from starting from node 1, until it cannot find any more paths, so after the recursion is over, we are left with this table:

| `_id` | `relates` | `lvl` | `_path` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `{2, 3}` | `1` | `{1}` |
| `2` | `{4}` | `2` | `{1, 2}` |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` | `2` | `{1, 3}` |
| `4` | `{3, 7}` | `3` | `{1, 2, 4}` |
| `5` | `{}` | `3` | `{1, 3, 5}` |
| `6` | `{}` | `3` | `{1, 3, 6}` |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` | `4` | `{1, 2, 4, 3}` |
| `7` | `{}` | `4` | `{1, 2, 4, 7}` |
| `5` | `{}` | `5` | `{1, 2, 4, 3, 5}` |
| `6` | `{}` | `5` | `{1, 2, 4, 3, 6}` |

After we filter out for `_id = 3` we get:

| `_id` | `relates` | `lvl` | `_path` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` | `2` | `{1, 3}` |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` | `4` | `{1, 2, 4, 3}` |

And it is always the case that the shortest path is the path that we hit first (since the edges have no weight). With the logic of our query that would be equivalent to the earliest returned record, so we can use LIMIT for this: limit 1

| `_id` | `relates` | `lvl` | `_path` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` | `2` | `{1, 2, 4}` |

And there is the shortest path from node 1 to 3.

My issue is the fact that this query computes **all** paths from node 1, making it awfully inefficient if the target node is near the start of the search. My goal is to make the query stop searching (completely) right after it hits the target node, since we know there will not be any other shortest path to come.

**I need a way to terminate the recursion completely when node 3 is reached.**

If i try to add a terminator for the node itself, such as the query below, the recursion for the other nodes at the same level continues, since the terminating condition is still satisfied:

```
    with recursive pathFrom1to3(_id, relates, lvl, _path) as
        (
            select _id, relates, 1 as lvl, ARRAY[_id]
            from graph
            where _id = 1
        union
            select g._id, g.relates, p.lvl+1 as lvl, _path || g._id
            from pathFrom1to3 p join graph g on g._id = any(p.relates)
            where not g._id = any(p._path) -- handles cycles (not applicable for this example)
            **and not p._id = 3**
        )
    
    select * from pathFrom1To3
```

produces:

| _id | relates | lvl | _path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `{2, 3}` | `1` | `{1}` |
| `2` | `{4}` | `2` | `{1, 2}` |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` | `2` | `{1, 3}` |
| `4` | `{3, 7}` | `3` | `{1, 2, 4}` |
| `3` | `{5, 6}` | `4` | `{1, 2, 4, 3}` |
| `7` | `{}` | `4` | `{1, 2, 4, 7}` |
| `5` | `{}` | `5` | `{1, 2, 4, 3, 5}` |
| `6` | `{}` | `5` | `{1, 2, 4, 3, 6}` |

Notice that the recursion stops for when node 3 is reached the first time; nodes 5 and 6 doesn't get searched further because node 3 was hit. But the recursion continues for node 4 (from node 2) because the p._id is not 3, it is 2.

We need a way to terminate the recursion when it reaches node 3 **for the entire level**.

My idea is to create a *reached* column which is 0 when the _id is not 3 and 1 when the _id is 3.
Then we can use SUM to check the sum of the reached values for the entire level and if it is not 0 then we terminate, but i am struggling to write this as a query.

here is my attempt at writing it:

```
    with recursive pathFrom1to3(_id, relates, lvl, _path, reached, lvlReached) as
        (
            select _id, relates, 1 as lvl, ARRAY[_id], 0 as reached, 0 as lvlReached
            from graph
            where _id = 1
        
        union
        
            select _id, relates, lvl, _path, reached, lvlReached from
        
            (
                select g._id, g.relates, p.lvl+1 as lvl, _path || g._id, 
                       case when 3 = any(g.relates) then 1 else 0 end as reached
                from pathFrom1to3 p join graph g on g._id = any(p.relates)
                where not g._id = any(p._path) -- handles cycles
            ) mainRecursion
        
            join
        
            (
                select lvl, sum(reached) as lvlReached
                from pathFrom1To3
                group by lvl
            ) lvlReached
        
            on mainRecursion.lvl = lvlReach.lvl
            where lvlReached = 0 
        
        )
    
    select * from pathFrom1To3
```

This gives me the error:

```
    recursive reference to query "pathFrom1to3" must not appear more than once.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try a window function to hold the status indicating the solution is found, causing all further recursive iterations to be pruned.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6jkIOIyr)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, vals, relates, done) AS (
   SELECT g._id, array[g._id], relates, null::int
     FROM graph AS g
    WHERE _id = 1
    UNION ALL
   SELECT g._id, vals||g._id, g.relates
        , MAX(CASE WHEN 3 IN (done, g._id) THEN 3 END) OVER ()
     FROM cte   AS c
     JOIN graph AS g
       ON g._id     = any(c.relates)
      AND NOT g._id = any(c.vals)   -- Avoid cycles
      AND done IS NULL              -- wait until we're done
     )
SELECT * FROM cte
 WHERE id = 3
;
```

The result:

| id | vals | relates | done |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | {1,3} | {5,6} | 3 |

By commenting out the `id = 3` logic in the last query expression, we see all the generated rows:

| id | vals | relates | done |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {1} | {2,3} | null |
| 2 | {1,2} | {4} | 3 |
| 3 | {1,3} | {5,6} | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

You can search from the bottom up, working backwards from `3` to `1`, thus decreasing the search space:

```
with recursive cte(id, vals) as (
   select g._id, array[3, g._id] from graph g where 3 = any(g.relates)
   union all
   select g._id, vals||g._id from cte c join graph g 
   on c.id = any(g.relates) and not g._id = any(c.vals)
)
select * from cte where id = 1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B9P5pQuk).

Comment: While this is correct for the data in the question, it doesn't work for my real data. 
That is because the starting node has connections to it too!
Think of the two nodes being in the middle of a huge graph, with connections all over the place.
Again the same issue arises if there are a bunch of connected nodes that lead to node 1.